# how to get selected file path in browse window?

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to upload file and get these file path in browsers window 
 I have selected file  using following code

**html**

```html
<input type="file" id="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)" *ngIf="slectedmethod=='UPLOAD'" #fileInput multiple>
```

**ts**

```js
onFileChange(event) {
  let reader = new FileReader();
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
    this.file = event.target.files
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.file);
  }
}
```

Comment: you can't get it because of security reason. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav)

Comment: window.open('yourpath','_blank');

Comment: I don't want to give a path.This can be anything on file selection

Comment: I want a path of file like var/www/html/abc.txt

Comment: I think you are right @zmag